# How can I add custom link data to a custom Deepview in Branch.io?

Tags: handlebars.js, branch.io

I've set up a Quick Link with custom link data like:

```
key: my_custom_param
value: test param
```

Then, when editing our custom Deepview, we use handlebars like this:

```
<p>{{link_data.my_custom_param}}</p>
```

We can't see this working at all.

**The question is**: is this possible? if so, how?

Documentation is non-existent on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out we were doing the right thing, and it works. The thing is that the Deepview takes a lot of time to update once you make changes, we were always seeing an old version of it.